# Shared folder sessions in Python

Tags: python, winapi, wmi, shared-directory

I'm trying to get a list of currently-open sessions in Python via WMI.

What I'm after is the exact information displayed in the Computer Management thingy, when you go to **System Tools** -> **Shared Folders** -> **Sessions** (ie username, computer name, connected time, that sort of thing).

I know (or at least believe) it has something to do with *Win32_ConnectionShare*...

If it makes a difference, I'm using [Tim Golden's wmi module](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi.html).

Of course, if there's another (non-WMI) way of getting this information then that's welcome too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind -- I found it:

```
>>> import wmi
>>> c = wmi.WMI()
>>> for x in c.Win32_ConnectionShare():
        print "%s: %s" % (x.Dependent.Username, x.Dependent.ComputerName)
```